# Android: draw GoogleMaps road route using many points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I  have for example more than two points on streets in my app, how to draw route between them depending on streets?`overview_polyline` from `Google Directions API` working only with 2 points at the time?Is it possible to make `Google Directions API` one request with many points and get `overview_polyline` route?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help  [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)